# Formtastic boolean/checkbox label not hiding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, formtastic

```
= form.input :success, label: false
```

The above code should hide the label but it doesn't. Any ideas why it's still showing the label?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the simple_form gem instead of formtastic.

EDIT: `label: ""` seems to be the (slightly hacky) solution if you are really intent on using Formtastic.

Comment: I don't want to change gems to fix this issue. I was wondering if there is a right way of doing that or maybe Formtastic just has a bug or something.

Comment: hmm... did you try label: nil?

Comment: `nil` does not fix it.

Comment: It might be a bit hacky, but try making it an empty string like so: :label => ""

Comment: `label: ''` seems to fix the issue. There might be a bug in Formtastic. Thank you for the suggestion.